# Session keys don't use asymetrical encryption?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, tls1.3

I'm learning about how https, SSL and TLS work. From what I learned, when you received a certificate from a certified server, you get a public key to encrypt your http requests, but what I'm not sure to understand is why your browser have to generate a key using symetrical encryption to encrypt a session key using the public key provided by the server.

From what I understand, symetrical encryption is less secure. Wouldn't it be easier to also create a public and private key and send it to the server, just like the server did with the client ? I want to understand why they choose this type of implementation.

Comment: Symmetric encryption is not categorically less secure (or asymmetric more so); it depends on the algorithms and parameters of each, and SSL/TLS applies them so that they are both sufficient and about equal. Asymmetric _encryption_ (only RSA) mostly hasn't been used for a session secret (not really a key) for about a decade; Diffie-Hellman secret agreeement combined with signature is used instead. Plus RSA encryption-decryption is hugely less efficient than symmetric; using it directly would take maybe 10 minutes to an hour per webpage. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem .

Comment: And this is not about programming or development at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming, and it is not specific enough for e.g. [security.se]. Please read the TLS specifications or some other resource explaining TLS for a layman before continuing.

Comment: "From what I learned, when you received a certificate from a certified server, you get a public key to encrypt your http requests" This is incorrect, you generally only authenticate the server with that public key. "your browser have to generate a key using symetrical encryption". No, that key is established using key agreement "to encrypt a session key using the public key provided by the server." and that one is derived, your source seems to be misleading you. Better buy a book or find a good tutorial.